# Is there a way on Windows to make a program wait for a debugger when it launches?

Tags: windows, debugging

Say program A launches program B. I want to debug program B. Is there a way to tell Windows, "when B.exe launches, let me attach a debugger before it starts executing," without having to modify the program?

Comment: You can use gflags https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/running-a-program-in-a-debugger